# Autocomplete with Int values

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have this method auto complete for names(string),
i want to create other method that completes Int Type, i try it but it says
cannot use LIKE for int type only for string

```
 void AutoComplete()
    {
        textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        AutoCompleteStringCollection Collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from stagiaire",con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            nom = dr.GetString(1).ToString();
            Collection.Add(nom);
        }

        textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = Collection;
        con.Close();
    }

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("nom like '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
    }
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from stagiaire",con);
        da.Fill(dt);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Column with DataType INTEGER use query like this:

```
select * from Table where Id like 1;
```

or convert it in to varchar:

```
 select * from Table where CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(45)) like '1%'
```